# pass jstl foreach variable to javascript function

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

I use jstl foreach loop to show my data.User can change the value and finally I want to send these data to server via jquery.
my problem is how can I pass loop variable to my jquery function when user changed the data and click on 'ok' button.
I used 
`<c:set var="chequeInfo" value="${cheque.chequeNo}~${cheque.amount}~${cheque.chequeDate}"/>`
to pass `chequeInfo` to `registerEdit()` function. but the value of this variable didn't change when user edit my data

```
<c:forEach items="${chequeList}" var="cheque">
<div class="row">
    <input class="date" type="text"
           value="${cheque.chequeDate}">

    <select id="chequeStatus">
        <c:forEach items="${chequeStatus}" var="status">
            <option value="${status.id}">${status.farsiName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>

    <label class="col-lg-3">${cheque.chequeNo} </label>

    <input type="text" value="${cheque.amount}">

    <button class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-1 btn btn-default register-edit"
            onclick="registerEdit('${cheque}','${status.id}')">ok
    </button>
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

how can I send `${cheque}` and `${status.id}` to `registerEdit()` function. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add varStatus attribute to you foreach tag, create unique id for your inputs,and pass the value of index to your registerEdit.

```
<c:forEach items="${chequeList}" var="cheque" varStatus="loop">
<div class="row">
    <input id="chequeDate-${loop.index}" class="date" type="text"
           value="${cheque.chequeDate}">

    <select id="chequeStatus-${loop.index}">
        <c:forEach items="${chequeStatus}" var="status">
            <option value="${status.id}">${status.farsiName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>

    <label class="col-lg-3">${cheque.chequeNo} </label>

    <input id="amount-${loop.index}"  type="text" value="${cheque.amount}">

    <button class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-1 btn btn-default register-edit"
            onclick="registerEdit('${loop.index}')">ok
    </button>
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

In your js function

```
function  registerEdit(index){
//get chequeStatus value like this
var chequeStatus = $("#chequeStatus-"+index).val()

//do same thing for other values

}
```

Comment: id="chequeDate-${loop.index}"